# User got saved in django regardless of other two forms with it are valid or not

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

UserForm got saved no matter if other two forms (StudentOrFacultyForm and UserIdForm) are valid or not. User should not be created if other two forms are invalid. Please help!

**models.py**

```
class StudentOrFaculty(models.Model):
    STUDENT = 'S'
    FACULTY = 'F'
    PROFILE_CHOICES = (
        (STUDENT, 'Student'),
        (FACULTY, 'Faculty'),
    )
    # Links to a User model instance
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='fors')

    # The Additional attributes
    st_or_faculty = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PROFILE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        if(self.st_or_faculty == 'S'):
            fullname = 'Student'
        elif(self.st_or_faculty == 'F'):
            fullname = 'Faculty'
        else:
            fullname = 'Unknown'
        return str(self.user) + " is " + fullname
class UserActivation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField(default=(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=1)))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural=u'Activation'

class UserIdCard(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    id_card = models.ImageField(upload_to='id_cards')
```

**forms.py**

```
FORS_CHOICES = (('F','Faculty'),('S','Student'))

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(help_text="Frist Name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(help_text="Last Name")
    username = forms.CharField(help_text="Username")
    email = forms.CharField(help_text="Email")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
        help_text="Password")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email',
            'password')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'this Email is already registered.')
        return email

class StudentOrFacultyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Studentorfaculty option
    """

    st_or_faculty = forms.ChoiceField(
                        label="Student Or Faculty",
                        required=True, 
                        choices=FORS_CHOICES,
                        widget=forms.RadioSelect, 
                        help_text="Student Or Faculty")

    class Meta:
        model = StudentOrFaculty
        fields = ('st_or_faculty',)

class UserIdCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id_card = forms.ImageField(label="College Id Card")

    class Meta:
        model = UserIdCard
        fields = ('id_card',)

    def clean_id_card(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get('id_card',False)
        if image:
            if hasattr(image,'_size'):
                if image._size > 4*1024*1024:
                    raise ValidationError("Image file too large (should be < 4mb )")
            return image
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Couldn't read uploaded image")
```

**views.py**

```
def user_signup(request):
    # get the request's context
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('notices:index'))

    # A boolean value for telling the template whether the signup was successfull
    # Set to flase initially. Code changes value to True when registration
    #successfull
    registered = False

    # If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Attempt to grab information
        # We make use of UserForrm and UserProfileForm
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        student_or_faculty_form = StudentOrFacultyForm(data=request.POST)
        user_id_card_form = UserIdCardForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        # If the two foms are valid
        if user_form.is_valid() and student_or_faculty_form.is_valid() and\
           user_id_card_form.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to the database.
            user = user_form.save()

            # Now we hash the  password with set_password method.
            # One hashed, we can update the  user object.
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()

            uid = user_id_card_form.save(commit=False)
            uid.user = user
            uid.save()

            fors = student_or_faculty_form.save(commit=False)
            fors.user = user
            fors.save()
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
            tmp = random.random()
            tmp = str(tmp)
            tmp = tmp.encode('utf-8')
            salt = hashlib.sha1(tmp).hexdigest()[:5]
            salt = salt.encode('utf-8')
            email_en = email.encode('utf-8')            
            activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt+email_en).hexdigest()            
            key_expires = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(2)
            email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
            #Get user by username
            user=User.objects.get(username=username)


            new_profile = UserActivation(user=user, activation_key=activation_key, 
                key_expires=key_expires)
            new_profile.save()

            # Send email with activation key
            email_subject = 'Account confirmation'
            email_body = "Hey %s, thanks for signing up. To activate your account, click this link within \
            48hours http://www.socialboard.in/accounts/confirm/%s" % (username, activation_key)

            send_mail(email_subject, email_body, 'support@socialboard.in',
                [email], fail_silently=False)


            # log in the user
            user_name = request.POST['username']
            '''new_user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],
                                    password=request.POST['password'])
            login(request, new_user)''' 

            # Update the variable to tell the registration was successful
            registered = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:aftersignup', kwargs={'user_name':user_name}))

        # Invalid forms 
        # Print problems to the terminal.
        # they will also be show to the  user
        else:
            print( user_form.errors, student_or_faculty_form.errors, user_id_card_form.errors )

    # Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two instance
    # These forms will be blank, ready for the user input.

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        student_or_faculty_form = StudentOrFacultyForm()
        user_id_card_form = UserIdCardForm()

    # Render the template depending on the context.
    return render_to_response(
            'accounts/signup.html',
            { 'user_form': user_form, 'student_or_faculty_form': student_or_faculty_form,
              'user_id_card_form': user_id_card_form,
              'registered': registered},
              context)
```

**signup.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="user_form" method="post" action="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data">

{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in user_form.visible_fields %}
<div class="form-group has-feedback">

<div class="col-sm-12"><input type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" class="form-control" name="{{ field.name }}"  placeholder="{{ field.label}}" value="{% if field.value %}{{field.value}}{% endif %}"></div>
{% if field.errors %} <div class="col-sm-10 text-danger"> {{ field.errors }} </div> {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% for fieldi in student_or_faculty_form.visible_fields %}
<div class="from-group has-feedback">
<!--<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">I am </label>-->
{% for value,text in fieldi.field.choices %}
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="{{ fieldi.name }}" id="" value="{{ value }}"><b> {{ text }}</b>
</label>
{% endfor %}
{% if fieldi.errors %} <div class="col-sm-10 text-danger "> {{ fieldi.errors }} </div> {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
<br>

{% for field in user_id_card_form.visible_fields %}
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<div class="col-sm-12"><b>{{field.field.label}} :</b></div>
<div class="col-sm-12"><input type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" class="form-control" name="{{ field.name }}"
    placeholder="{{ field.label}}" value="{% if field.value %}{{field.value}}{% endif %}"></div>
{% if field.errors %} <div class="col-sm-10 text-danger"> {{ field.errors }} </div> {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Provide a button to click to submit the form -->

  <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-10">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><b>Sign Up</b></button><br><br>
  <div>or have an account? <a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}"><span class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Log In</span></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you specify what problem you have? Why are the other two forms not valid?

Comment: suppose if user does not specify if he is student or faculty( choice) then user should not be created but in my case User is created.

Comment: Are you putting three separate forms into one and then check their validity separately?

Comment: although i have written right code for it in the views.py 
` if user_form.is_valid() and student_or_faculty_form.is_valid() and user_id_card_form.is_valid():`

Comment: Yeah now I got where the problem is.So have to put them into separate forms in .html file?

Comment: What is the value of `student_or_faculty_form.st_or_faculty` in the view at runtime?

Comment: But in which form should i put submit button?

Comment: It shows the error the field is required but User is created and student_faculty_form doesn't save.

Comment: How do you know that some forms are not valid? Do you get the page rendered with errors?

Comment: Yeah I get the error when signup page is rendered.